# Decoding XML object from mssql in Python

Tags: python, sql-server, xml

I get back an XML object from a mssql server when I call a SP from Python (2.7). I get it in the following form:

```
{u'XML_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B': 'D\x02i\x00d\x00D\x05d\x00e\x00s\x00c\x00r\x00D\x0bd\x00a\x00t\x00a\x00t\x00y\x00p\x00e\x00_\x00i\x00d\x00D\x13e\x00n\x00u\x00m\x00e\x00r\x00a\x00t\x00i\x00o\x00n\x00_\x00t\x00y\x00p\x00e\x00_\x00i\x00d\x00D\rs\x00y\x00s\x00t\x00e\x00m\x00f\x00e\x00a\x00t\x00u\x00r\x00e\x00D\x04l\x00i\x00n\x00k\x00D\x07F\x00e\x00a\x00t\x00u\x00r\x00e\x00\x01\x00\x08F\x00e\x00a\x00t\x00u\x00r\x00e\x00S\x00A\x01\x07A\x01\x01A\x03B\x01\x00\x00\x00\x81\x01\x01\x02A\x03\x11\x1a\x00r\x00e\x00s\x00p\x00o\x00n\x00d\x00e\x00n\x00t\x00_\x00i\x00d\x00\x81\x02\x01\x03A\x03B\x01\x00\x00\x00\x81\x03\x01\x05A\x03F\x01\x81\x05\x01\x06A\x03F\x00\x81\x06\x81\x07\x01\x07A\x01\x01A\x03B\x02\x00\x00\x00\x81\x01\x01\x02A\x03\x11 \x00W\x00o\x00r\x00k\x00s\x00 \x00a\x00t\x00 \x00c\x00o\x00m\x00p\x00a\x00n\x00y\x00\x81\x02\x01\x03A\x03B\x01\x00\x00\x00\x81\x03\x01\x05A\x03F\x01\x81\x05\x01\x06A\x03F\x01\x81\x06\x81\x07\x01\x07A\x01\x01A\x03B\x03\x00\x00\x00\x81\x01\x01\x02A\x03\x11\x0c\x00G\x00e\x00n\x00d\x00e\x00r\x00\x81\x02\x01\x03A\x03B\x08\x00\x00\x00\x81\x03\x01\x04A\x03B\x01\x00\x00\x00\x81\x04\x01\x05A\x03F\x00\x81\x05\x01\x06A\x03F\x00\x81\x06\x81\x07\x81\x00\x08F\x00e\x00a\x00t\x00u\x00r\x00e\x00S\x00'}
```

I have two questions:

- 1: What encoding is this?
- 2: What library should I use to decode this?

Addition:

The XML as it shows in the SQL Management Studio:

[image]

The SP:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[rdb_sql2python]

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SELECT * FROM [_rdb].[dbo].[features] FOR XML RAW ('Feature'), ROOT ('FeatureS'), ELEMENTS
    SET NOCOUNT OFF
END
```

Comment: what charset did you use in your db?

Comment: Just to get this clear: There is a SP living in a SQL Server. This returns XML and the string you are posting is what arrives in the calling `Python` code as return value. Correct so far? At the first sight this looks like `JSON`, on the second sight this seems to be a list of encoding signs, which might be `BSON`...

Comment: @Shnugo: yes you are correct. I will look into what BSON is and come back to you. Thanks so far.

Comment: @MichelTouw As a first attempt I'd use a scalar function returning XML rather than a stored procedure, where the caller must guess the returned type. You might create a function returning `NVARCHAR(MAX)` and return your XML as unicode string... K.I.S.S.- principle... And you might show the code, where you call this. I'm not familiar with Python, but other people are...

Comment: Doing the unicode thing works, but the xml that will be used MAY be bigger than the 4000 characters from the `NVARCHAR()`. So that's why it must be something else, preferably the XML object.

Comment: @MichelTouw If you think about text-size... Just look at this snippet from your `BSON`: `\x0bd\x00a\x00t\x00a\x00t\x00y\x00p\x00e` See the last characters of each group? This is the word `datatype` but taking 5 times the space of normal text... You might cast your XML to `NVARCHAR(MAX)`, which is `UTF-16` and then to `VARCHAR(MAX)`, which is `UTF-8`. This doubles the max-size to ~8000 characters and works, as long as you do not use very *far-away* characters like *middle-east*, chinese or tamil. And you might think about `BASE64` or - if you are using SQL-Server 2016 - native JSON query...

Answer (score 1):

I try something like an answer, at least to the question: What is this:

At [this JSON-viewer](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/) your string as you presented it did not work. But when I removed the "u", replaced the single quotes with double quotes and removed the "D" it worked somehow:

This string

> {"XML_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B":
>   "\x02i\x00d\x00D\x05d\x00e\x00s\x00c\x00r\x00D\x0bd\x00a\x00t\x00a\x00t\x00y\x00p\x00e\x00_\x00i\x00d\x00D\x13e\x00n\x00u\x00m\x00e\x00r\x00a\x00t\x00i\x00o\x00n\x00_\x00t\x00y\x00p\x00e\x00_\x00i\x00d\x00D\rs\x00y\x00s\x00t\x00e\x00m\x00f\x00e\x00a\x00t\x00u\x00r\x00e\x00D\x04l\x00i\x00n\x00k\x00D\x07F\x00e\x00a\x00t\x00u\x00r\x00e\x00\x01\x00\x08F\x00e\x00a\x00t\x00u\x00r\x00e\x00S\x00A\x01\x07A\x01\x01A\x03B\x01\x00\x00\x00\x81\x01\x01\x02A\x03\x11\x1a\x00r\x00e\x00s\x00p\x00o\x00n\x00d\x00e\x00n\x00t\x00_\x00i\x00d\x00\x81\x02\x01\x03A\x03B\x01\x00\x00\x00\x81\x03\x01\x05A\x03F\x01\x81\x05\x01\x06A\x03F\x00\x81\x06\x81\x07\x01\x07A\x01\x01A\x03B\x02\x00\x00\x00\x81\x01\x01\x02A\x03\x11
>   \x00W\x00o\x00r\x00k\x00s\x00 \x00a\x00t\x00
>   \x00c\x00o\x00m\x00p\x00a\x00n\x00y\x00\x81\x02\x01\x03A\x03B\x01\x00\x00\x00\x81\x03\x01\x05A\x03F\x01\x81\x05\x01\x06A\x03F\x01\x81\x06\x81\x07\x01\x07A\x01\x01A\x03B\x03\x00\x00\x00\x81\x01\x01\x02A\x03\x11\x0c\x00G\x00e\x00n\x00d\x00e\x00r\x00\x81\x02\x01\x03A\x03B\x08\x00\x00\x00\x81\x03\x01\x04A\x03B\x01\x00\x00\x00\x81\x04\x01\x05A\x03F\x00\x81\x05\x01\x06A\x03F\x00\x81\x06\x81\x07\x81\x00\x08F\x00e\x00a\x00t\x00u\x00r\x00e\x00S\x00"}

converts to

```
Name: XML_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B
Value: "idDdescrDdatatype_idDenumeration_type_idD systemfeatureDlinkDFeatureFeatureSAAABArespondent_idABAFAFAABA Works at companyABAFAFAABAGenderABABAFAFFeatureS"
```

This is - for sure - not the final solution, but it's clear, that this is BSON encoded JSON.

It might be a good idea to show (the relevant parts of) you(r) SP and the way you are calling this. Might be, that there is a completely different / better approach...